# Steam Analytics change my event time data

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I am newbie sorry my stupid question.

I send my json data from my gatewayApp and I set the eventtime DateTime.Now(UTC+03:00)

I can write to database data as same before the 13.00 AM
but after 13.00AM everythings changed 
My database time from the GetDate() is UTC even my json data I send event time UTC+3 but output data is UTC

How is that posible AMK.

Comment: not the answer to your question but i suggest you stick with UTC for obvious benefits like consistency in the cases of time zone changes or day light saving. is it really necessary that application uses UTC+03:00?

Comment: Ya bacanak benim anlamadığım gönderdiğim jsonda ben Utc+03.00 le yolluyorum bunu nasıl kendi kafasına göre Utc çeviriyor zaten yeniyiz iyice bıraktık beyni böyle sacma sapan şeyler yüzünden

Comment: Bacanak dedin ya koparttin beni emmioglu :)  `_date.getTimezoneOffset();` olarak alican sonra js de

Comment: `var _istanbulOffset = 3*60*60000;
var _userOffset = _date.getTimezoneOffset()*60000;
var _istanbulTime = new Date(_date.getTime()+_istanbulOffset+_userOffset);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong. We expect to address this limitation in the next month or sooner. Sorry about the inconvenience.

Comment: Thx For Answer.